# VB.NET never get focus on any control

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

i have developed a simple calculator like in windows calculator,

but unlike in windows calculator, after clicking any button, the focus on that button is still there on the particular clicked button.

so how to never get focus for all buttons on calculator form ... ?

i don't think that it will better to write loose focus code on every button's click event ... so any better solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any code of yours, I am going to assume that you have a text box that displays the numbers pressed by the user, so you need to set the focus to the text box once a user clicks a button, like this:

```
TextBox1.Focus()
```

Note: If your text box is not named `TextBox1`, then change the name to whatever your text box is actually named.

Comment: i dont want to set focus on even the `textbox`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a standard button use an instance of a **NoFocusButton** class derived from the Standard button. In this class override the **ShowFocusCues** property and return always false.

```
Form f = new Form();

// Need to add manually the buttons to your form unless you build a customcontrol
NoFocusButton b = new NoFocusButton();
b.Text = "ClickMe";
f.Controls.Add(b);
f.Show();

// Class derived by the Button control, it is identical but the
// property that control the drawing of the Focus rectangle returns FALSE
// tricking the WinForm system to avoid to draw the focus rectangle
class NoFocusButton : System.Windows.Forms.Button 
{ 
    protected override bool ShowFocusCues 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return false; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

The credit goes to [Remove Focus Rectangle from Button](http://dotnetstep.blogspot.com/2009/06/remove-focus-rectangle-from-button.html)